# React Native picker resets after value change

Tags: react-native

I have used react picker and resets back to previous values.The setState on the OValueChange also doesn't worked

```
pickerChange(index) {
  this.setState({
     ingred_value: this.props.filterData.ingredients[index].value,
     ingred_id: this.props.filterData.ingredients[index].id
});

<Picker
  mode='dropdown'
  selectedValue={this.state.ingred_value}
  style={{ marginStart: 10 }}
  onValueChange={(itemIndex) => this.pickerChange(itemIndex)}
>

 {
   this.props.filterData.ingredients.map((v) => 
   {
     return <Picker.Item label={v.value} value={v.id} key={v.id} />
   })
 }
</Picker>
```

Comment: What do you mean by setState doesn't work ? Does it go in your pickerChange function ? Or just it setState to nothing ? Did you logged index in your function, is it the correct value ?

Comment: Does it go in your pickerChange function ? Yes .
Or just it setState to nothing - no i have set the recent updated value. 
 Did you logged index in your function. yes i am getting the values in the function

Comment: @VAIBHAVYADAV did you manage to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 potential issues with your code:

1. Your `selectedValue` property of your `Picker` component is set to `this.state.ingred_value` (which contains the value not the id), but the `value` property of your `PickerItem` component is set to `v.id`. This means that when you change your `ingred_value` state value, the Picker will not be able to match the new state with the id values in the PickerItem to select it in `selectedValue`. You should use `ingred_id` instead.
2. The `onValueChange` method's first argument is the value (v.id) and not the index of the item selected (take a look [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/picker#onvaluechange)). So unless your items ids start from 0 and are sequential then it might not match the index, in which case you wouldn't be selecting the correct item in the array (`ingredients[index]`) and it would throw an error if the item doesn't exist. You should change it to `onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.pickerChange(itemIndex)}`.

Below code should work:

```
pickerChange(index) {
   this.setState({
     ingred_value: this.state.filterData.ingredients[index].value,
     ingred_id: this.state.filterData.ingredients[index].id
   })
 }

 render() {
   return (
     <Picker
       mode='dropdown'
       selectedValue={this.state.ingred_id}
       style={{ marginStart: 10 }}
       onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.pickerChange(itemIndex)}
     >
     {
       this.state.filterData.ingredients.map((v) => 
       {
         return <Picker.Item label={v.value} value={v.id} key={v.id} />
       })
     }
     </Picker>
   );
 }
```